# How to send multiple functions/options to more than one list item?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview, javadoc

In my Profile.java class I have listview and I registered it for context menu and passed two items in profile.xml file named General and Silent. What I want is, when user click on General, it must show only Activate option and when user will select Silent, it should show deactivate. Activate and Deactivate options are in my context_menu.xml file.

I am giving you all of my files.

Profile.java

```
Activity activity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

         activity = this;
        //List Items

          ListView lv  = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.profile)));




    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //menu.add("hello");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);


        }
```

profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="profile">
        <item name="General">General</item>
        <item name="Silent">Silent</item>



    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Context_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:title="@string/Activate" android:id="@+id/item1"/>


        <item android:title="@string/Deactivate" android:id="@+id/item2"/>

    </menu>
```

Comment: Add some of your code samples so we can see what youre doing/trying to do

Comment: What are you trying to do? React to a aspecific ListView item click?

Comment: We can't help you without your code

Comment: I have provided all of my code

Comment: @Nick cardoso .................

Answer (score 0):

```
yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        final int position, long id) {
        your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using listView not a list. Which code i have to write here in this function?

Comment: @maciej does the above comment show you why it's not exactly a good idea to answer bad questions, or do you need more nonsense ?

Comment: I think it's enough :D

Comment: I thought so :) As a rule of thumb, I always check the questions record of the OP before answering any question. You can tell the above is going to be a waste of time by looking at OP's previous questions : no accepted answer, all comments asking for code are always ignored, and technical level is below RTFM. OP just wants his problem fixed, any attempt to teach anything will be met with indifference.

Comment: I have provided my code. Hopefully it will not waste your time and give you idea what exactly iwant to ask..